# Bounded function from open interval to $R$

Tags: real-analysis

$(a,b)$ is an open interval in $R$, assume $f: (a,b) \to R$ is continuous, prove that if 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x)$ exist, then $f$ is a bounded function.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $\alpha\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\lim_{a^+} f$ and $\beta\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\lim_{b^-} f$ both exist, then define $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ as 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x\in(a,b) \\ \alpha & x=a \\ \beta & x=b\end{cases}
$$
Then, $g$ is continuous (can you see why?), and defined on a compact $[a,b]$. Thus, it is bounded (Extreme Value Theorem). But then so is $f$.

Comment: why g is continuous?

Comment: Because it is $f$, extended by continuity.

Answer (score 1):

If the limits exist, then you can extend $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ to a function $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by defining $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ to be the appropriate limits. Now $g$ is a continuous function on a compact set. What now?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L = \displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) \Rightarrow \exists \delta_1 > 0$ such that if $a < x < a + \delta_1$, then $|f(x) - L| < 1$. So $|f(x)| - |L| \leq |f(x)-L| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq 1+|L|$. Similarly let $K = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) \Rightarrow \exists \delta_2 > 0$ such that if $b-\delta_2 < x < b$, then $|f(x)-K|<1$. So $|f(x)| - |K| \leq |f(x)-K| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq 1+|K|$. We can always choose the deltas such that: $a < a + \delta_1 < b - \delta_2 < b$. Thus: if $x \in (a,a+\frac{\delta_1}{2})\cup (b-\frac{\delta_2}{2},b)$ then $|f(x)| \leq 1 + |K| +|L|$. And on the closed interval $[a+\frac{\delta_1}{2},b-\frac{\delta_2}{2}]$, $f(x)$ is continuous hence bounded and achieves a maximum there. Call it $M = \sup\{f(x): x \in [a+\frac{\delta_1}{2},b-\frac{\delta_2}{2}]\}$. We have: $\forall x \in (a,b), f(x) \leq \text{max}(M,1+|K|+|L|) = B$, and
$A=\text{min}(-|M|,-1-|K|-|L|) \leq f(x)$. So $A \leq f(x) \leq B, \forall x \in (a,b)$, proving it is bounded.